# How can I prevent MEF from throwing an exception when an Export is not found?

Tags: .net, mef

I have a class with an `IList<T>` property decorated with the `[ImportMany(allowRecomposition = true)]` attribute. There are some conditions in which the application might not find any available Exports of the requested type. Right now, it's throwing a CompositionException if no Exports of the requested type are found. I dislike application flow being determined by thrown exceptions, so I would rather not catch and react in this case. Rather, I just want program execution to continue.

Is there a flag or something I can set to make this Import optional? I know for single import properties, you can do this: `[Import(AllowDefault = true)]` but '`AllowDefault`' is not an option on the `ImportMany` attribute.

Comment: Hi - can you please include the details of the exception message in your post, as well as the signature of your importing constructor/property? This isn't expected behaviour - ImportMany allows zero-to-many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There most be something else failing because by definition ImportMany will allow zero or more items, so if there isn't a value it will not cause any errors.

Comment: You're exactly right. It was something else causing the error. Thanks for your time on this.